# how to predict election turnout using previous data?

Tags: bayesian

I am trying to predict election turnout based on previous (historical) data without advanced machine learning, how can I use **Bayesian Theorem** to predict which candidate has how much chance of winning the election?

Comment: This question looks like it is better asked at [stats SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: hey there , I am new here can you please tell me how can I move this thread there ? thanks .

Comment: I've cast a vote to move it to CV.SE